# Wordpress: поменять адрес для всех записей определенного типа

Tags: php, wordpress

В Wordpress есть два способа открыть какой-либо пост:

1. example.com/имя_категории/название_поста/
2. example.com/название_поста/

И если ввести url из 1 варианта в адресную строку, Wordpress перенаправит запрос на 2 вариант.

Мне нужно обратить это поведение для **одной определенной** рубрики. Т.е. все запросы к ней без префикса `/имя_категории/` должны дополняться префиксом.

Встроенными средствами этого не сделать, поэтому я хочу узнать, где нужно копаться, чтобы поменять поведение wordpress-а на этот счет.

Comment: почему вы не можете? создаете раздел в записях, переносите записи в этот раздел, у раздела указываете урл blog

Comment: Обновил текст. Мне нужно запретить доступ по url без /blog/

Comment: ковыряйте htaccess

Comment: Не выйдет т.к. на этапе htaccess нельзя узнать, в какой рубрике запись

Comment: Возможно тебе помогут настройки Link Mask Generator в плагине SEO Ultimate

Comment: 1) Версия Wordpress? 2) Какие плагины установлины?

Comment: 4.4.1. Никаких плагинов, которые влияют на переадресацию или имена страниц.

Answer (score 1):

может вам вместо одной определённой рубрики создать [кастомный тип постов](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) и настроить для них нужный вид ссылок?

Comment: Я бы не хотел переносить уйму уже существующих материалов на другой тип постов с риском ошибок и всего прочего

Comment: На мой взгляд, это вполне адекватное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Быстрый поиск по гитхабу принес "**wp_redirect**"

1. Находим функцию в коде `wp-includes/pluggable.php`
2. Пытаемся найти путь по которому проиcходит вызов(стэк).

   - **xdebug** ... ставим точку разрыва и смотрим стэк. ИЛИ
   - Создаем там ошибку `throw new Exception('fake');` и получеем стэк как ошибку.(Не забудьте потом удалить)
3. Хорошо думаем что, как и где поменять. Саму функцию **wp_redirect** не трогаем, проблем не оберешся!

Comment: и после обновления опять производить эти манипуляции?

Comment: @kandellak Собственно поэтому есть пункт 3. Читайте внимательнее.